# JSCalc for loop statement

Tags: javascript

**Javascript beginner**

Trying to create a compound calculator, but then it only displays one row (year, investment value). How do I get the calculator to display table of investment values from year 1 to year n?

```js
'use strict';
var ir=inputs.interestRate/100;
var yr=inputs.years;

return{
returnz:[{
  'years' : yr,
  'returnValue': inputs.value*(Math.pow((1+ir),yr))
  
}]
};
```

The webpage:
https://jscalc.io/calc/OaVdNdV6sRENdT66

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The value that you're returning in returnz is a list that has only one element, containing the last year and its associated interest rate.

You need to initialize an empty list and add each year with a for loop:

```
'use strict';
var ir=inputs.interestRate/100;
var yr=inputs.years;

var years = [];
for(var year = 1; year <= yr; year++) {
  years.push({
    'years' : year,
    'returnValue': inputs.value*(Math.pow((1+ir), year))
  });
}

return{
  returnz: years
};
```